# How to create a new field in access through JDBC

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am looking for a way to insert a field/column into a record in MS-Access through Java. I believe that I need to use executeUpdate(INSERT...), however I cannot seem to get my program to add new fields/columns. Any help would be appreciated, and an example of the correct line would be even better.

Thanks,
~Crash

Comment: Please provide your code sample, and welcome to SO.

Comment: There is a difference between modifying the data in a table (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) and modifying the structure of the table itself (e.g. `ALTER TABLE`).  A sample of your code would be useful as it's not clear what you want to accomplish and how you have tried to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new field (column) to an existing table you can use an ALTER TABLE statement like this:

```java
String connectionString = 
        "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
        "DBQ=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.execute("ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN Address TEXT(255)");
```

For more information on ALTER TABLE see

[ALTER TABLE Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883%28v=office.12%29.aspx)